# What will be layout res folder for Resolution 1208*800 px, Density 240 dpi, screen size 8 inch in Android

Tags: android, layout

In my application I need to configure layout res to support 8 inch tab. This has resolution 1208*800 px, density 240 DPI. What will be the folder name for layout res. `layout-sw600dp` and `layout-sw720dp` both not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dpi of 240 is 1.5x of normal dpi (160 dpi). So we should divide 800 pixels by 1.5 and then we get approximately 533.3 dp. So you should use `layout-sw533dp`

Answer (score 0):

After Long try i got solution

```
layout-sw360dp-xhtml
```

And design with 5.1 inch screen size